# Parsing WSDL with Java is so slow

Tags: java, performance, web-services, wsdl

I'm parsing WSDL with Java, the performance is so poor. When I first execute the code, it will take about 7 secs; the total average is about 2 secs.

It would not have been caused by the network, because I tested it locally. This is what I'm doing:

```
WSDLParser parser = new WSDLParser();
Definitions defs = parser.parse(url);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, such behavior *could* be caused by huge `maxOccurs` values in the XML Schema definition in the WSDL. I suggest you look for any `maxOccurs`/`minOccurs` value larger than say 999 in your WSDL/XML Schema and replace them with "unbounded" if you find any. For details, see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6483188